# Why am I getting an index was outside the bounds of the array exception?

Tags: .net

The code below works, but it throws an exception message box every time. The message box says " index was outside the bounds of the array". I would like to not see the messagebox, but I would also like to not have an empty exception catch. What have I done wrong?

```
private void btnReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;

        OpenFileDialog oFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (oFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = oFD.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);

                    while (sr.Peek() >=0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < myStream.Length; i++)
                        {

                            string[] lines = sr.ReadLine().Split(new Char [] { '\t' },    StringSplitOptions.None);

                            string one = lines[0];
                            string two = lines[1];
                            string three = lines[2];

                            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { one, two, three });

                            lvRollResults.Items.Add(item);

                        }

                    }

                    sr.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

==================================UPDATE==========================================
After reading and adding PSL's code to mine I ended up with a new exception (object referenced is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my new code. I changed to while loop looking for a null and added a reaLine() inside the while loop.  This code now works with no exceptions.

```
private void btnReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;

        OpenFileDialog oFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (oFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = oFD.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);

                    while ((sr.ReadLine()) != null)//if line is null stop reading
                    {
                        string[] lines = sr.ReadLine().Split(new Char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                                string one = lines[0];
                                string two = string.Empty;
                                string three = string.Empty;

                                if (lines.Length > 1)
                                    two = lines[1];

                                if (lines.Length > 2)
                                    three = lines[2];

                                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { one, two, three });

                                lvRollResults.Items.Add(item);
                                sr.ReadLine();//read a line to see if it is null

                    }

                    sr.Close();

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not to be an ass, but did you try debugging?

Comment: I did, but I did not understand it, so I came here so you would explain it to me in English. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is the new null reference exception being thrown?

Comment: @BrianDawson I can't speak for everyone, but I prefer to help those who show they've tried to solve the problem themselves. There's no one standard for all questions or askers, and sometimes you're just plain stuck and don't know what to do next, but it would help to at least indicate you've put some effort in. If you've debugged and have been able to see the exception, there's a bunch of information there that you or someone else can use to isolate the problem. If you've debugged but haven't been able to reproduce it, that's also useful to know (though ideally you'd have a test case).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the array `lines` does not have 3 elements. Don't try to access array indices larger or equal to the array's length.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong in this place.

```
 string[] lines = sr.ReadLine().Split(new Char [] { '\t' },    StringSplitOptions.None);

 string one = lines[0];
 string two = lines[1];
 string three = lines[2];
```

Without even checking the `length` of the `lines array` you are trying to pull items out of it. This must be the place where you are receiving the error too. What if there is less than 2 `\t` in the line that you are reading. This will fail with `Index out of bounds`.

Instead what you can do is

```
string one = lines[0];
string two= string.Empty;
string three = string.Empty;

if(lines.Length > 1)
 two = lines[1]
if(lines.Length > 2)
 three = lines[2];
```